# Exploit VS Reverse Engineering VS PenTest

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, vulnerability, reverse-engineering

To start let me say that I'm trying to find my way in infoSec...I wanna know which path to follow. My background is basic database CRUD programming (HTML Php, JavaScirpt, Java etc...)

I just read an  [cnn article about a yahoo major data breach](http://money.cnn.com/2016/09/22/technology/yahoo-data-breach/index.html)
They say it was "an individual" sponsored by some state...

So I thought that individual might be a pentester, reverse-engineer (i.e. vulnerability researcher), exploit writer ....

My question is : what would you recomment a beginner to do if its goal is to go from "zero knowledge (i.e that knowledge being my current programming background)" to "expert knowledge" ?

For instance for the summer holidays (3 to 4 months no school sitting at home studying infosec), how should I study at least one of the follwoing fields to reach some intermediate level at the end of the summer holidays :

- exploit writing (I like that field becaus I know a little programming) ;
- reverse engineering (vulnerability researching) ;
- pentesting ;
- name anytoher field I am not aware of

... some sort of roadmap with textbooks if possible.

Comment: Sorry, but this is primarily opinion-based. There are lots of places you can go research these things, but this site isn't really for questions like this. You may get a better response at [The DMZ chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz), or on channels like `##security` or `#r_netsec` over on Freenode IRC.

Comment: @silverpenguin My budget is not a problem. I know a good library where I can get all sorts of books

Comment: @Polynomial hmm... Dont have enough reputation to start talking on DMZ....The IRC is only  showing people logging in / out... pretty confusing

Comment: @JohnSebastian Yeah, IRC can be pretty quiet. Just ask your question and be patient. Not sure why you're unable to join the DMZ, I'll see if I can invite you in there. [EDIT: Nope, doesn't look like I can.]

Comment: @Polynomial it says "You must have 20 reputation"

Comment: I am going to suggest you study the PWK from offensive-security.com this will give you everything you have asked for on a basic level and then gives you virtual lab access over VPN to which you can go wild and hack into machines until your fingers bleed, it teaches you the very basics, then you learn through doing.

Comment: @silverpenguin Now I undertand you question about money. Offensive security is out of my league as far as budget is concerned Yeah I saw that...for penetration testing with kali Linux...This is more of a Pentest stuff if I'm correct. From what I undertsand, this is like ADVANCED script kiddy stuff. I like it. I saw some cbtnuggets related to it. It doesnt teach the writing. And to be honest it. What I'm looking is something like PWK but for exploit writing and reverse engineering vulnerability reseach AND CHEAPER that Offensive security

Comment: @JohnSebastian I dont know who you are, but i will find you. within this course you get to understand much more than that. you would learn the bread and butter of exploit development (i.e. buffer over flows). sure it feels a little script kiddy to start with, but thats the easy stuff. if you want to learn this stuff by your self thats easy, the hard part is practice. to write exploits, good onces, you need to understand what you are looking for....this is a really in depth conversation to have in comments...

Comment: @silverpenguin  Haha You will find me ? I'm using a guest account but I do have a stack* (* = overflown, exchange, etc...) account. If you are interrested, I'd really like to continue this conversation somewhere esle than comments section. How can we contact each other ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several technical and non-technical jobs in infosec, but for web developers, with your profile, I would recommend you to read about web applications and it's flaws.

Pentest is usually a several steps activity, when it is executed by a team, maybe only a few members have a good knowledge about more than one field. Exploit writing is really vague, if you plan to write buffer overflows (stack, heap), the basic of assembly is fundamental, but if you keep your focus in web applications, that won't be necessary.

There is not much books or recommendations on the web for a final complete book that you read and magically get all knowledge. Usually what you will read is the technical documentation for the application, man pages, and books on your field. For a good start, install DVWA, get used to read code, understand the vulnerabilities in your field of study (php/java), learn how to exploit it. It would be an easier start it by spending hours debugging your shellcode into gdb. Let those steps for another moment and you will see the results faster.

In parallel with that, keep collecting old versions of software, get used to docker and vagrant, because you will use it a lot to build your test environments.

And keep the magic rule that, you **should** be able to know how to do certain activities to be someone able to execute a vulnerability assessment on that field. You will really often be asked "but how we fix it ?", if you just print and send a scan report, you will never be really able to get in touch with that kind of activity.

Besides technical skills, you will spend most of your time explaining the impact of a vulnerability to a customer, and how to fix it. Happens a lot, a guy exporting a Nessus report to pdf and sending it via e-mail. This usually isn't something that IT managers keep an eye on, once I worked for a company that just want a second opinion, the result, their main Oracle database was **pwned** in a matter of a day, with all that hosts in the path compromised too. Now imagine your reputation in the market, after 2 years of just mailing Nessus reports saying that the environment is 100% ok, their finished their contract with the other company in the same day. But that is what happens when people don't work in their area of expertise. That auditor is an excellent professional, with a lot of knowledge on internal processes, ISOs, PCI and security policies, mistakes happen, but never touched an Oracle database, an Open VPN Server, a Cisco router and a Windows Server. Without a deep understanding of a topic, you won't be able to perform a complete pentest on that platform. As an example the same will happen with me if I try to make a vulnerability assessment on a Solaris, what will happen is a lot of google research and several tasks executed because I've read about it, in other words, it would be better results just running Nessus, because my testes would in lack consistency and is possible that I leave something behind.

Another field that may interest you is incident response. If you were able to get a degree in law too, or know a good lawyer to partner with, you will be able to perform the whole response. But you will need to be versatile, know from blocking a DDoS attack, to write a firewall rule, fix a php file inside a production server, parse old application logs to generate a white list in a matter of minutes. Basically is to mitigate the attack, recover from the attack, gather evidence, do the legal aspects of the activity and help the investigators with your gathered evidence.

Like all kind of business, you should think about what is the value of your work to your customers, and a pentest/vulnerability assessment **should result in a better understanding of security level of your customer, giving as result what you tested, how you tested, what you found, and what your customer need to do to archive the security level that is needed**.

Comment: What you are saying (on the programming part) is that I should learn how to write exploits for the stuff I know (java/php...i e no Assembly no opcodes for now) then when I am "fluent" in it go deeper and with maybe gbd and finding solutions/patches ...  Also I think you mean that it's easier to master a specific topic (for instance writing php exploit, or pentest with kali) that to master several topics right ?

Comment: You got it right ! Let's suppose that you want to analyse the security of a wifi solution in your customer, he uses WPA2 with EAP, you won't find an automated tool to extract the usernames from the traffic, neither a script that will brute force those users, and it's something that a basic "wifi l33t h4ck3r" would bother to look or know how to attack, they just use wifite, aircrack and airodump. And very often you are asked to fix those vulnerabilities, so be ready to that. And Kali is a Linux distribution with several tools, consider it a multipurpose all in one swiss army knife, not a field